# Decide macro based on the value of variable

Tags: c++

I want to use a particular macro depending on the value of variable.
How can we do that in c++?

Example:

```
#define ONE 1
#define TWO 2
#define THREE 3
#define FOUR 4

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    i = fun();
    if (i == 1)
        printf("%d\n", ONE);
    else if(i == 2)
        printf("%d\n", TWO);
    else if(i == 3)
        printf("%d\n", THREE);
    else if(i == 4)
        printf("%d\n", FOUR);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I do this without using so many if else statements?

Comment: You can use a `switch` statement. Or declare a `std::map<int,int>`.

Comment: You wouldn't do that. C++ is such an expressive language that it usually allows you to solve your problem in C++ rather than in the preprocessor.

Comment: All in all your sample could be shortened to `printf("%d\n", fun());`.

Comment: You do that exactly the same as if you had written `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` instead of `ONE`, `TWO`, `THREE`, `FOUR`.

Comment: if you are sure that  fun() will give 1 or 2 or 3 or  4 then print the value of "i" directly. What is the use of macros here?? simply you can write printf("%d",i);

Answer (score 1):

You may use switch:

```
switch(fun()) {
    case 1: printf("%d\n", ONE); break;
    case 2: printf("%d\n", TWO); break;
    case 3: printf("%d\n", THREE); break;
    case 4: printf("%d\n", FOUR); break;
    default: break;
}
```

or array in your case:

```
const int ints[] = {ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR};

const int i = foo();
if (1 <= i && i <= 4) {
     printf("%d\n", ints[i - 1]);
}
```

For sparse values (for `i`), a `std::map` should replace the array.